# Why do so many American students, even English Secondary Education majors, 'hate' English grammar?

Tags: grammar

I've been teaching a (pedagogical) English Grammar course to English Secondary Education majors in a public university for several years. I spent a lot of time thinking of ways to make the course easy to understand and fun. To some extent, it worked. However, I do notice a consistent pattern that students enter this class with quite negative attitudes towards grammar.

In the first course assignment named "Grammar and I", one of my students wrote, "Grammar became this very limiting, stringent, elitist set of rules that does serve a purpose, but seems to go well past any purpose it serves into obscure, pedantic rules that don’t actually help many people." At this point, we've already discussed the differences between 'prescriptive' and 'descriptive' grammar and variations in grammar. Such an attitude has prevented this student from taking the course seriously and making decent progress.

As a second-language English writer, I'm well aware of the power of grammar. However, I found it hard to convince my native English-speaking students that they can benefit from it too.

I feel for the decline of grammar instruction at schools since the 1980s. I do believe that grammar knowledge can be useful for students in English, Composition & Rhetoric, law, journalism, and many other professions that require strong writing competence.

My questions are: Shall we bother to 'make a fuss' about grammar education, or it indeed deserves more serious attention? What can grammar teachers do to initiate positive changes?

Comment: The student who wrote "Grammar became this very limiting, stringent, elitist set of rules ... " gets an A+ for language and speaking truth to power. Address that sentiment and your job is done.

Comment: This question is off-topic here as it's not specifically an English-language issue, and a matter of opinion not fact. But it's certainly true giving people a list of rules tends not to impress them, especially if they seem arbitrary or useless. Maybe you could emphasise the fact that grammatical rules must be discovered by examining actual speech/texts, not invented.

Comment: Have you told them about the difference between the grammar of spoken and written English?  Even uneducated speech follows grammar rules. dialectal ones. So, they don't realize it but their own speech follows grammar rules, just not the fancy ones, That is true every time they open their young mouths.

Comment: The two examples you give from your syllabus ("_differences between 'prescriptive' and 'descriptive' grammar and variations in grammar_") lead me to believe that you are not teaching what the student you quote is railing about. Since the term grammar has negative connotations for some students you may wish to consider changing the course title to _language awareness_, for example. This term came into use in the UK in the 1980s, in recognition of the fundamental importance of language for the whole curriculum.

Comment: Also, it is a bit of stretch to describe American students this way; this truism could apply to young people in any language. Most teenagers hate anything involving disciplined thinking.

Comment: Can you clarify if this question is about US vs UK? Middle school or high school? Students disdain for grammar vs -teachers- of English not liking to teach grammar?

Comment: @StuartF I think there's room on ELU for this kind of sociolinguistics, peoples attitudes towards learning language, about English specifically. But I do think this question (once clarified) might work better on [languagelearning.se]

Comment: Oh, I misread... it's about -college- students who may become teachers of English, so sort of in between secondary school student and teacher of those students.

Comment: I would suggest you're encountering hate not for grammar itself but for how grammar instruction has been used in your students' pasts. "Pedantic" suggests they have been judged harshly for small errors before. So I'd ask them to elaborate. The answers may be enlightening.

Comment: English has actually one of the easiest grammars compared to other languages (Germanic or not). They should check out Hungarian or Finnish, for example. As most people don't learn other languages beside their mother tongue and English, they have no idea what is out there. Although, I agree that even native speakers don't use or know all grammar rules or concepts; and you don't need to in colloquial speech. IMO, the difficult part of English is the rich vocabulary and pronunciation/spelling irregularities.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like more of an opinion piece.
I fall into the category that grammar and vocabulary are powerful tools for communicating ideas in a precise and concise manner. However, my experience has shown that using words like "perspicuity" in conversation leaves others confused.

Consider the following: Person A communicates a high-level idea to Person B, who does not understand. Person A changes their vocabulary and syntax, likely shortening sentences, in order to simplify the idea to Person B. Because Person A could not communicate at a high level, they received negative feedback from their interaction, reinforcing the idea that **communication at a high level (ie. proper grammar and expanisive vocabulary) does not work.** Person A then changes their behavior to be better understood next time because "proper grammar and verbose vernacular make communication less effective and dissuades users from its inherit power."

Not to mention, people just sound ludicrous when they are caught unaware of their poor grammar.

EDIT:

Yes, it think it is worth making a fuss over. Though I do not have a background as a professional educator, I found that simple grammar/vocabulary exams did wonders when I was in secondary school. Not obtrusive, but small, consistent practice exams (maybe 8% of the grade so it won't ruin students who don't care, but bolster those who do) that challenge students with new words and applications of grammar and vocab.

Comment: Generally, I gear my conversation to my interlocutor's level. Obviously, you can't use perspicuity with everyone. Or assiduity for that matter.

Comment: I have to add assiduity to my lexicon! That's a good one.
Exactly. Meeting people where they're at may become a slippery slope in the grand scheme, from my opinion.

Comment: I simply cannot understand your second and third paragraphs.

Comment: Rewritten. Maybe I need to study some more English and grammar myself... yeesh.

TLDR: When the interlocutor has a different level of comprehension, communication patterns must be simplified.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answers. We've discussed prescriptive vs. descriptive grammar, register- and dialect-based variations, and data-driven grammar. Most students are able to change their attitudes after learning about these differences. I've also added rhetorical grammar (how grammar can be applied to improve writing). Many students appreciate this and wrote in their self-assessment reflections that knowing grammar helped them to be more aware of their language use in writing. I'm just frustrated by those who cling to the preexisting negative attitudes toward grammar and don't learn.